# Get my login in middle of screen, both vertical and horizontal

Tags: html

I have created an html file called Login. Here i have made a form with an userId input, and password input.

I want my login form to be in the middle of the screen (not just align="center"), anyone knows how to handle that?

**my code so far:**

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Please Login!</title>

<style>
body {
position: relative;
}

#form-relative {
width: 300px;
height: 200px; 
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px; 
margin-left: -150px; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body style="background-color: #ECF6FE">

<div id="form-wrapper">
    <form method="post" id="Login" action="validateLogin.jsp">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter userID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userid"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Enter password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><br> <input type="submit" value="Login" />  <input
                    type="reset" value="Cancel" /><br /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </form>
</div>

<div></div>

<h6 align="center">Note! An admin operator must use "admin" as
    username and "masterkey" as password</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [you really shouldnt use tables for layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: your HTML is invalid.  You are missing a `</td>` on line 11 of that snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set width and height you could use some CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="form-wrapper">
        <form>
            <!-- Your form here -->
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

#form-wrapper {     
    width: 300px;           /* Set this to your convenience */
    height: 200px;          /* Set this to your convenience */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;     /* Half of height */
    margin-left: -150px;     /* Half of width */
}
```

Comment: please , i have edited my code, but it still dosen't work, is my style right set up?

Comment: Change #form-relative to #form-wrapper in your CSS, as that's the name of your selector. Also, make sure <html> is being open at the start of your file (assuming you just copied a partial code)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the thing.  First of all, this will never work unless you have a fixed width and height.  It just doesn't work to have a dynamically sized container centered in HTML/CSS as far as I have seen so far.  If you can have a set width and height, however, it's easy.  My favorite method is setting `position:absolute` and giving `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` attributes `0` and setting `margin:auto`

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Jj422/

```
form {
    width: 300px; /* this is needed */
    height: 200px; /* this is needed */
    padding: 10px; /* this is for styling only */
    background: #eee; /* this is for styling only */

    position: absolute; /* this is needed */
    margin: auto; /* this is needed */
    left: 0; /* this is needed */
    right: 0; /* this is needed */
    top: 0; /* this is needed */
    bottom: 0; /* this is needed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your form in another div and give that div these styles:

margin-left:auto;

margin-right:auto;

text-align:center;

Good luck!

Comment: How should i write it? says an error here.

<div margin-left:auto margin-right:auto text-align:center;>

Comment: margin-left = auto; says its undefined name

Comment: <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;">ur form</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
body,html,#root
{
height:100%;
}
#form-wrapper
{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}


#login
{
height:50%;
width: 50%; 
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words as to how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry am not able to add comments

Comment: Use the `edit` link under your answer to add an explanation, not comments.